# Animation Translate using LayoutParams

Tags: android, translate-animation

Basically i want to create translate animation but for some reason i cannot use TranslateAnimation class. Anyway this is my code

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"      
  android:id="@+id/layout"   
  android:orientation="vertical"     
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">   
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.test2;

import android.app.Activity; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout; 
import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams; 
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{   

  private RelativeLayout layout;   
  private ImageView image;   
  private LayoutParams imageParams;

  @Override   
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)   
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    imageParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    image.setLayoutParams(imageParams);
    layout.setOnClickListener(new ClickHandler());   
  }

  class ClickHandler implements OnClickListener   
  {
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
      // This is the animation part
      for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
      {
        imageParams.leftMargin = i;
        image.setLayoutParams(imageParams);
        // repaint() in java
        try
        {
          Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
      }
    }   
  }
}
```

My problem is I need to do repaint() before using Thread.sleep otherwise the animation will not work and the object will just move to its final position. I've tried invalidate, requestLayout, requestDrawableState but none works. Any suggestion?

EDIT:

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/layout"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
  private RelativeLayout layout;
  private ImageView image;
  private LayoutParams imageParams;
  private Timer timer;
  private int i;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    image = new ImageView(this);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    imageParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    image.setLayoutParams(imageParams);
    layout.addView(image);
    i = 0;
    timer = new Timer();
    runOnUiThread
    (
      new Runnable()
      {
        public void run()
        {
          timer.scheduleAtFixedRate
          (
            new TimerTask()
            {
              @Override
              public void run()
              {
                imageParams.leftMargin = i;
                image.setLayoutParams(imageParams);
                i++;
                if (i == 15)
                {
                  timer.cancel();
                  timer.purge();
                }
              }
            }, 0, 100
          );
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Where have you used animation in your code ?

Comment: I want to create animation by adding leftMargin and looping so the image looks like moving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
</RelativeLayout>


package com.example.example;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    ImageView imageView;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;
    int i=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        imageView=new ImageView(this);
        RelativeLayout main=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.main);

        params=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
        main.addView(imageView);
        final Timer timer=new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        params.leftMargin=i;
                        imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
                        i++;
                        if(i>=100){
                            timer.cancel();
                            timer.purge();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }, 0, 100);


    }


}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
you can use timer task instead of sleep
Like:-
int i=0;
Timer timer=new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 imageParams.leftMargin = i;
        image.setLayoutParams(imageParams);
                i++;
                if(i==100){
                    timer.cancel();
                    timer.purge();
                }
            }
        }, 0, 1000);
```

Comment: Thx for the reply. But I guess image.setLayoutParams(imageParams) in run() method causes runtime error somehow

Comment: you can use  runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
      
     }
    });   to avoid Error

Comment: try to add imageview programetically not by xml this will work

Comment: I've added imageview programmatically but still got error. maybe i should update my post so you could see whether i code it wrong or not..

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

</RelativeLayout>